# Getting button list from a window menu - AppleScript

Tags: button, menu, applescript, itunes, automator

I can get a main menu item and I have been able to use system events to select and click a specific button in a window. I am running into an issue where i want to get the 'handles' of buttons that belong to a popup 'sheet'. For instance, the "airplay" button in iTunes:

[image: In this case there are 2 items]

I can get the button to click to open the sheet using something similar to this:

```
click button 10 of window "iTunes" of application process "iTunes" of application "System Events"
```

and I COULD use `key code` to manually scroll up and down, though I am looking for a most efficient and elegant solution of selecting the specific button I want (by name ie: "Computer" in this case)

I am using the accessibility Inspector and I can get some info about the menu:

```
<AXApplication: “iTunes”>
 <AXWindow: “iTunes”>
  <AXMenu>
   <AXMenuItem: “AirPort Express”>

Attributes:
   AXRole:  “AXMenuItem”
   AXRoleDescription:  “menu item”
   AXParent:  “<AXMenu>”
   AXEnabled:  “1”
   AXPosition:  “x=1070 y=798”
   AXSize:  “w=146 h=22”
   AXTitle:  “AirPort Express”
   AXHelp:  “(null)”
   AXSelected (W):  “1”
   AXMenuItemCmdChar:  “(null)”
   AXMenuItemCmdVirtualKey:  “(null)”
   AXMenuItemCmdGlyph:  “(null)”
   AXMenuItemCmdModifiers:  “0”
   AXMenuItemMarkChar:  “(null)”
   AXMenuItemPrimaryUIElement:  “(null)”

Actions:
   AXCancel - cancel
   AXPress - press
```

So do these popups have a specific title? Like `select button 1 of sheet 1 of...`

I think this is likely easy and I am over thinking the issue.

cheers!
bo

WHAT IVE TRIED:

```
    --click menu item "Computer" of menu 1 of window "iTunes" of application process "iTunes"
    --tell application "System Events" to tell process "iTunes"
    --  tell menu 1 of menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
    --      click menu item "Copy"
    --  end tell
    --end tell
    --click (every button whose value of attribute "AXTitle" is "Computer") of window "iTunes" of application process "iTunes"
    --tell window 1
    --click button "Computer" of tool bar 1 of window "iTunes" of application process "iTunes"
    --  click button 1 of group 1 of group 1 of window "iTunes" of application process "iTunes"
    --end tell
    click (menu item 2 of every menu item whose attribute "AXRoleDescription" is "menu item") of window "iTunes" of application process "iTunes"
    --click (button whose description is "menu item") of window "iTunes" of application process "iTunes"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible on customized menu : `<Window "iTunes"> --> <Menu>`

It's possible on a popup button. `<Window "iTunes"> --> <popup button> --> <Menu>`

You must continue to use the `key code`.

Comment: I was afraid someone would say that!!! cheers! (i will leave it open a bit longer just in case!)

Answer (score 0):

The hierarchy shown in the **Accessibility Inspector** is what you need to use.  The menu is not available until it gets popped up though, so you may need to wait a bit - I don't have any external speakers to test, but you would do something like:

```
tell application "System Events"
    click button 10 of window "iTunes" of application process "iTunes"
    delay 1 -- give menu time to pop up
    click menu item "Computer" of menu 1 of window "iTunes" of application process "iTunes"
end tell
```

You might also be able to use `click menu item "Computer" of front menu` after popping up the menu.  If the indexes are not right, you can usually backtrack thru the hierarchy by popping up the menu, then get the menus to find the correct index, then get the menu items of the menu, etc.

Comment: No, because **System Events (accessibility)** doesn't find these menus.
Use this line after the delay `return menus of window "iTunes" of application process "iTunes"`, the result --> **{}**

Comment: thats a great piece of diagnostics! Thanks I will use that in the future!